# Change event precedence with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have the following html code:

```
<input type="text" id="theInput" value=""/>     
<a href="#" id="theLink">Click me</a>
```

I want to detect when the input changes and perform an operation in this case, but ONLY when the user has not clicked in the link. I have tried this:

```
$('#theLink').live('click', function(){
  alert('click');
});

$('#theInput').live('change', function(){
  alert('change');
});
```

However `change` is always executed before `click` when the value in the input changed, due to Javascript event precedence rules, and therefore only "change" message is displayed.

I would like it to display `change` only if the input value changed and the user exited the input clicking in any other place instead of the link. In that last case I would like to display `click`.

The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hTqNr/1/).

I use jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: good question! i m interested in the answer here...

Comment: I updated my answer , i finally understood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `click` event fires after the `blur` and `change` events in every browser (have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/YFuKd/)). The order of `blur` and `change` is different across browsers (source: [Nicholas Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/02/06/event-order-of-blur-and-change/)).

To solve your problem, you could listen to `click` events on the document and compare the event's target with `#theLink`. Any click event will bubble up to the document (unless it is prevented).

Try this:

```
var lastValue = '';

$(document).click(function(event) {
    var newValue = $('#theInput').val();

    if ($(event.target).is('#theLink')) {
        // The link was clicked
    } else if (newValue !== lastValue) {
        // Something else was clicked & input has changed
    } else {
        // Something else was clicked but input didn't change
    }

    lastValue  = newValue;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/TTwEG/

Comment: Seems to work, but I am a little worried in terms of performance when capturing all `click` events in the page.

Comment: @Pablo: is it likely that the user will click so much that it will make a noticable difference?

Comment: Ok, I have finally opted for something similar to your solution. Thank you very much. Final solution JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hTqNr/27/) in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now i got it, you could do

```
$('#theLink').live('click', function(e){
    alert('click');
});

$('#theInput').live('change', function(e){
    //Check if the change events is triggerede by the link
    if(e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.data === "Click me"){
         //if this is the case trigger the click event of the link
         $('#theLink').trigger("click");
    }else{
        //otherwise do what you would do in the change handler
        alert('change');
    }
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hTqNr/19/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Ok, now I see. The previous error happens when using Chrome browser, but works with Firefox.

Comment: This is a nifty solution, but only works in Gecko-based browsers. Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.explicitOriginalTarget#Specification)

Answer (score 1):

Both events will fire but in your example the alert in the `onchange` event handler fired when the `onmousedown` event occurs will stop the `onmouseup` event required for the `onclick` event to fire. Using `console.log` will show both events firing.

http://jsfiddle.net/hTqNr/4/

Answer (score 0):

why you dont pick the value of input box. you have to store initial value of input box on ready function

```
 initialvalue= $('#theInput').val();
```

then compare the value

```
 $('#theLink').live('click', function(){
    var newvalue =$('#theInput').val();
        if(newvalue!=initialvalue) {
            //do something
         }

  });
```

Comment: With your code I don't get the `change` message when the value changed and the user clicks outside the link. Furthermore, what I want is that when the user clicks the link I don't care about the value change.